# Is it true that $E[\|X_{n+1}-E[X_{n+1}|\sigma(X_n)]\|^p] \leq E[\|X_{n+1}\|^p]$ when $p\ge2$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have seen in a paper to use (this is my understanding, I may be wrong) the following for $p \geq 2$:
$$
E[\|X_{n+1}-E[X_{n+1}|\sigma(X_n)]\|^p] \leq E[\|X_{n+1}\|^p]
$$ 
where the norm is Euclidean norm and $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov process.

I sense Hilbert space projection idea here but that works only for $p =2$.

Comment: I love it that you reverted the title to its irrelevant form. Think again.

Answer (score 3):

This is false, even for a trivial $\mathscr{F}_n$. I believe that this is false for each $p>2$, but will show for $p=4$.

Let $X = 1$ with probability $x$ and $-1$ with probability $1-x$. Then $E[X^4] = 1$, $$E[(X-E[X])^4] = x (2-2x)^4 + (1-x)(2x)^4.$$ E.g., for $x=1/4$, we have 
$$
E[(X-E[X])^4] = \frac{21}{16} > 1.
$$

---

Here is a simple argument why this cannot be true for all $p\ge 2$. In fact, the inequality is equivalent to $||X-E[X|\mathscr{F}]||_p\le ||X||_p$, so by letting $p\to\infty$ we would get $\operatorname{ess\,sup} |X-E[X|\mathscr{F}]|\le \operatorname{ess\,sup} |X|$, which is definitely false. And my example uses this idea: you ensure that $\operatorname{ess\,sup} |X-E[X]|>\operatorname{ess\,sup} |X|$.

Comment: Here $X_n$ is a Markov process. Therefore $E[X_{n+1} | \sigma(X_n)] = \int y p(dy|X_n)$.

Comment: Can it be true then ?

Comment: @Sosha, it does not matter. Let $X_{n+1}=X_n+X$ with $X$ independent of $X_n$ and distributed as in my example.