# In expectation, does conditioning reduce moments beyond the second?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I know that conditioning on a random variable, in expectation, reduces variance. This is a consequence of the law of total variance. Formally, I refer to the following:
$$E[Var(x|y)]=Var(x)-Var[E(x|y)]\le Var(x)$$
where equivalence holds only in the case of independence. 
My question is whether this type of argumentation extends to higher moments. In particular, is it the case that: $$E[(x-E(x|y))^k]\le E[(x-E(x))^k]$$
for $k>2$ and arbitrary distributions of $x$ and $y$? Intuitively, I believe it must hold for $k$ even, but haven't thought of a suitable proof technique. I'm not sure whether or not it will hold for $k$ odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. I will show this for $k=4$, modifying my construction from **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450626/is-it-true-that-e-x-n1-ex-n1-sigmax-n-p-leq-e-x-n1-p/)**, where a somewhat related question is discussed.

Let $X = \pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ so that $\mathsf{E}\left[\big(X-\mathsf{E}[X]\big)^4\right] = \mathsf{E}\left[X^4\right] = 1$. Let further $Y = X$ with probability $1-x$ and $-X$ with probability $x$. Then, given $Y = 1$, $X = 1$ with probability $1-x$ and $-1$ with probability $x$. Therefore, $\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=1] = 1-2x$ and 
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\big(X-\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=1]\big)^k\mid Y=1\right] = x(2-2x)^4 + (1-x)(2x)^4
$$
and similarly for $Y=-1$. Consequently,
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\big(X-\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y]\big)^k\right] = x(2-2x)^4 + (1-x)(2x)^4.
$$
Taking, for example, $x=1/4$, we get 
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\big(X-\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y]\big)^4\right] = \frac{21}{16}> 1 = \mathsf{E}\left[\big(X-\mathsf{E}[X]\big)^4\right].
$$

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!